# Tipsy Tooltip Direction Problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

I use Tipsy Tool time plugin I noticed that I cant use the same direction of the tooltip with another link.

Example:

javascript:

```
$('#south').tipsy({gravity: 's'});
```

html:

```
<a id='south' href='#' title='This is an example of south direction'>South</a>
<a id='south' href='#' title='This is an example of south direction2'>South</a>
```

Explain the example:

Link1 - link2

when I hover link1 the tooltip shows at the top,
I want also when I hover link2 the tooltip shows at the top,

But unfortunately did not work with me!

So can any one help me.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't repeat IDs like this, they have to be unique in a page (otherwise you'll see side-effects, like `$('#south')` only returning the first match...your current issue).  Use a class instead in these cases, like this:

```
$('.south').tipsy({gravity: 's'});
```

The same on the links;

```
<a class='south' href='#' title='This is an example of south direction'>South</a>
<a class='south' href='#' title='This is an example of south direction2'>South</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response I tried your solution and its worked,